# Cannot find module 'esprima'

Tags: javascript, node.js, esprima

I'm trying to develop an Abstract Syntax Tree program in JavaScript. I'm using Jet brains IDE for development. When I run the program, i get the error *Cannot find module esprima*. The nodejs settings are perfect and, I don't think there is any problem with it. Please find the code snippet below. In one article, I saw that esprima module is present in the nodejs. Please help. Thank You.

```
var esp = require('esprima');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your project's `node_modules` directory for `esprima`. If it is not there try to install it using the following command in terminal,

From your command prompt terminal, change your directory to your project's root directory.

Use `WinKey + R` to run command prompt. Then run `cmd`, and in cmd execute change directory command.For example, if your project is in `C` drive then,

```
C:
```

This will change to C: drive, then locate your project directory.

```
cd project_directory
```

Change `project_directory` with yours. Then install module using,

```
npm install esprima
```

Otherwise try to update it using,

```
npm update esprima
```

Comment: I'm using Windows and also newbie to using Jetbrains. Please explain. Thank You

Comment: @Sandesh Good, best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) 7 (which is nearly complete as I write this), I'd suggest the following steps as it's simple.

In WebStorm 7+, you can quickly get to an embedded command line for your project by using the `Tools` menu option, `Open Terminal...`. From there, you can manipulate the installed node packages easily. If you aren't using a version of WebStorm that has the option, simply switch to the root directory of your Node.JS application and perform the same steps.

If you don't already have a `package.json` file defined for your node.js project. Add it.

You can either manually create the file or use

```
npm init
```

from the console and follow along with the prompts (press `[Enter]` once or twice to move along from field to field).

You can then add **esprima** as a dependency manually to `dependencies` as shown below:

```
{
  "name": "nodetemp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Best demo ever",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD",
  "dependencies": {
    "esprima": "*"
  }
}
```

In the example above, I've specified I wanted to use whatever the current version of esprima is located on npm.org. (Which is OK for development purposes more than likely, but less ideal for production unless carefully managed.)

Or from the command-line use `npm` again:

```
npm install esprima --save
```

This will download the current version of **esprima** and add it as a dependency in the `package.json` file. It will automatically associate the current [semantic version](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html) of **esprima** with your package.

If you use the `--save` option, it currently would add the following to the `package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "esprima": "~1.0.4"
  }
```

Once the dependency is listed in the `package.json` file, you can always use:

```
npm update
```

from the root directory of your application to update it (or download it fresh if it's not yet locally available).